# proximityMonitoring may not be working as intended

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

for my iOS app i want to implement a feature where the screen should turns off (like when you answer a phone call) when the device is faced down.
so I've started by detecting the device orientation:

```
//in my ViewDidLoad
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.rotated(_:)), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

//called when the device changes orientation
    func rotated(notification: NSNotification){
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceDown{
            print("device = faced down")
        }else{
            print("device != faced down")
        }
    }
```

when device is down i've called

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled = true
```

else

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled = false
```

the problem is `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` seems to act a little bit late so when the `rotated()` function is called, the device is already faced down and it turns out that in order for  `proximityMonitoringEnabled = true` to turn off the screen the proximity sensor should not be already covered !
I'm pretty sure that this is an Apple limitation but maybe someone out there did found a solution or came across a workaround!
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach:**

Since iOS doesn't provide before changing Orientation we couldn't rely on '*UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification*'. Instead we can use CoreMotion Framework and access hardware's gyroscope for detecting possible FaceDown orientations and set proximityMonitoringEnabled appropriately.

**Gyroscope Data:**

Using Gyroscope observations below values can possibly detect FaceDown Orientation.

```
let gyroData = (minX:-3.78, minY:-3.38, minZ:-5.33, maxX:3.29, maxY:4.94, maxZ:3.36)
```

**Solution in Swift:**

```
class ProximityViewController: UIViewController {

    let cmManager = CMMotionManager(), gyroData = (minX:-3.78, minY:-3.38, minZ:-5.33, maxX:3.29, maxY:4.94, maxZ:3.36)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Using GyroMotion
        experimentCoreMotion()
    }

    //MARK: - Using Core Motion
    func experimentCoreMotion() {

        if cmManager.gyroAvailable {

            //Enable device orientation notification
            UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

            cmManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.1

            handleFaceDownOrientation()

        }

    }

    func handleFaceDownOrientation() {

        cmManager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: { (data:CMGyroData?, error: NSError?) in

            if self.isGyroDataInRange(data!) {

                UIDevice.currentDevice().proximityMonitoringEnabled = (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .FaceDown)

                if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .FaceDown {  print("FaceDown detected") }
                else { print("Orientation is not facedown") }
            }
        })
    }

    func isGyroDataInRange(val: CMGyroData) -> Bool {
        return ((val.rotationRate.x > gyroData.minX && val.rotationRate.x < gyroData.maxX) &&
            (val.rotationRate.y > gyroData.minY && val.rotationRate.y < gyroData.maxY) &&
            (val.rotationRate.z > gyroData.minZ && val.rotationRate.z < gyroData.maxZ))
    }
}
```

Hope my solution solves your query. Let me know the solution is working fine for your requirement.

**Gyroscope & Accelerometer Observations:**

I've experimented the possible values of FaceDown orientation using Gyroscope & Accelerometer. IMO, Gyroscope data seems fine but it's open to explore other hardware's sensors to detect FaceDown Orientation.

Comment: while your code successfully detected the facedDown status but my problem still persist 
"in order for proximityMonitoringEnabled = true to turn off the screen the proximity sensor should not be covered already"
i think that your solution is the way out but i have to play more with the value to kind of detect (device will rotate to faced down)! ill wait for others solutions while experimenting with your code ! and ill mark it as a valid answer as long a get a success !

Comment: Hmm okay I'll check and update my answer accordingly.